# What's wrong with my maze checker??? (JAVA)

Tags: java, stack

So we are given a maze with walls(W) open path(O) a start pt (S) and a finish pt (F).

I am trying to write an algorithm that takes the maze file and then turns it into a 2D array of points to make a grid.

Once I have the grid, I want to start on the 'S' character in the maze and try to find whether or not it is possible to traverse through the O's to get to the F. (Return a boolean true/false)

I know that this maze is solvable, so why am I getting 'false'??  There must be a complicate problem because all I get is the plain boolean false, not the "sorry, maze isnt traversable"...

Here is the Maze1.txt file:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Here is my code(new attempt):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;

public class MazeExplorer {
    static Point startPoint = new Point();
    static Point finishPoint = new Point();
    final static int mazeHeight = 12;
    final static int mazeWidth = 58;
    static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
    Stack<Point> pointsNotTraversed = new Stack<Point>();
    Point pt = new Point();
    static HashSet<Point> previousLocations = new HashSet<Point>();
    static Stack<Point> nextPoints = new Stack<Point>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name of your Maze");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        File f = new File(console.nextLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        if(!sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a file name with the extension, that contains a maze!");
        }
        System.out.println("So, you want to know if your maze is solvable.....?");

        for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
            final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
            mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
        }
            //identify the finish point
        for(int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<mazeWidth; j++){
                if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'F'){
                    finishPoint = new Point(i, j);
                }       
            }
        }
        // Identify the start point
       for(int i = 0; i< mazeHeight; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++){
               if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'S'){
                 startPoint = new Point(i , j);
               }
           }
       }
       isTraversable(startPoint);    
    }
        public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){
            boolean isSolvable = false;
            do {
                mazePoints[current.x][current.y] = ' ';

                if (mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] == 'O'){ //up dir
                   nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y - 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] = ' ';  //'X' marks where you've already been          
                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] == 'O'){ // below direction
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y + 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] = ' ';        
                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] == 'O'){ // to the right
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x + 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] = ' ';
                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] == 'O'){ // to the left
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x - 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] = ' ';             
                }
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x] == 'F'){
                    isSolvable = true;
                    System.out.println("MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!");
                }
                current = nextPoints.peek();
                nextPoints.pop();
                isTraversable(current);         
            } while(!current.equals('F') && !nextPoints.isEmpty());         
            return isSolvable;          
        }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Perhaps the approach is off? I would probably look at a maze as a series of blocks. Each block (the inside of the maze) will allow you to move in one of 3 directions (not including where you came from). Each of those 3 directions would be true or false. Just check the value and move through that way.

Comment: @leigero - No, if you try to do that, you end up stuck in an endless loop if there are any circuits in the maze.

Comment: Perhaps a series of boolean checks to see if I can move in that direction?

Comment: @DavidWallace Well you could store the path you visited to prevent that. That wasn't a complete analysis of the problem.

Comment: Sure.  For myself, I'd just use the original array, changing O to V (visitable) if I detect I can get to a square.  If I end up trying to change F to V, I return true.  If I get stuck with no more V cells to add, I return false.

Comment: @leigero exactly..every already visited location is pushed onto the stack pointsTraversed

Comment: What does the actual `.txt` file look like?

Comment: @leigero see edit in question

Comment: the points you've traversed don't need to be put onto the stack. You can store it any way you want to just make sure you dont visit the same place twice. The things you should push onto the stack should be all the neighbors of the square you are currently in

Comment: You basically want to use a DFS algorithm. Except it needs to be formatted to work with your array instead of a tree.

Comment: @bazookyelmo to support stakSmashr comment, you are thinking of the Stack in the wrong way. Your stack should only be initialized with your starting Point. You then pop the starting point from the Stack and add the points children to the Stack. You loop through this behavior until your Stack is empty or you have found the Goal Point. i recommend studying the Depth First Search Algorithm on Wikipedia. It provides easily understandable pseudocode.

Comment: @BrianVanover thanks! This helped a lot!  How do I indicate the start point with my code though? I try to push the point 'S' onto the point stack but 'S' is only a char?

Comment: @bazookyelmo I provided a solution for initializing the starting point as an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the algorithm:

```
do
    mark current spot in the array as "visited" (can use any symbol you want)
    push all of the neighbors not yet visited onto the stack
    current spot <-- top of the stack to visit the next spot
    pop the stack
while (exit is not found && stack is not empty)
```

Just wrote this in 5 min, let me know if there are bugs.

EDIT (with respect to OP's edit):

Your `canMove<direction>` methods are too complicated, there's actually no need o make such functions, much less check the stack. Also, either your traverseMaze function should take in a row and col argument for the starting position, or you should put such information inside your class as private variables.

Simply do something like

```
//assuming that current spot is at r,c
if (mazePoints[r-1][c] == 'O'){ //up dir
    pointsInMaze.push(new Point(r, c));
    mazePoints[r-1,c] = '';  //empty char marks where you've already been
}
//other directions ommitted here
```

Now all you have to do is put the above into the loop in the algorithm provided and it should work. Note that I changed the "mark current spot in the array as 'visited' line to "mark neighbors as visited" here because checking whether a point exists inside the stack is not efficient. Much easier to just mark them as visited as you push them into the stack. However, you still need to mark your starting position as visited when you begin your loop

Comment: I tried implementing your idea... I might have understood it wrong or wrote it wrong(total noob here!! Sorry!)  I also wrote some boolean methods to check in all directions in case I use a different algorithm...would they work??

Comment: Yeah, the second line should probably be "push all of the neighbours not yet visited and not currently on the stack".  +1 though - this is the right answer.

Comment: user3349062 - You're asking us whether your methods work?  Without showing them to us?  Bring me my crystal ball!  The best way to find out whether they work though is to test them, rather than relying on strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Anyone got code for a crystal ball?! (Boy, would that be cool!)  I just mentioned that note mostly so nobody thinks I'm crazy for writing a bunch of methods and not using any of them!  I'm more concerned about correctly implementing @stakSmashr 's algorithm..

Comment: another interesting idea is that, you can actually have multiple threads to speed this process up, you can have thread 1 with starting point as S and store the visited nodes in set A and thread 2 with starting point as F and store the visited nodes in set B. After they start to traverse, we can have another thread to check if set A intersects with set B.

Comment: @stakSmashr Can you see my newest edit? I'm having trouble with the iteration....

Comment: @bazookyelmo Looking at your code, it looks to me that you probably should try coding something a little simpler to start and familiarize yourself with object oriented programming and Java in general. I did, however, annotate your code but I doubt I can paste it here. Shoot me an email (see my profile) if you want it.

Comment: Could you guys take a look at my new version?

Comment: @bazookyelmo that looks about right, if it doesn't work, do some debugging, but the general logic of your function seems correct

Answer (score 1):

Another thought using a stack.

psuedo code:

```
push starting point to path stack
lastStepValid = true
while (stack is not empty && goal not found) {
  lastStep = peek the top of path stack


  if (lastStep == goal) {
      goal found = true
  } else if (not lastStepValid) {
    leave last step poped
    if (path stack is not empty) {
      pop path stack
      lastStepValid = true
      if (lastStep is UP of top of path stack) {
          push RIGHT of top of path stack to path stack 
      } else if (lastStep is RIGHT of top of path stack) {
          push DOWN of top of path stack to path stack
      } else if (lastStep is DOWN of top of path stack) {
          push LEFT of top of path stack to path stack
      } else {
          lastStepValid = false
      }
    }
  } else if (lastStep is wall || lastStep exists more than once in the stack) {
      lastStepValid = false;
   } else {  // last step is valid
      push the UP of lastStep to path stack
   }
}
```

in brief, you have a stack to store the path you have walked, and try every step in the sequence of up, right, down left.

This approach doesn't require you to flag cells in the maze.

Answer (score 1):

You asked in the comments of your question how to find the starting point. You can find the starting point during the initiation of your mazePoints array

```
    Stack<Point> stack = new Stack<Point>();
    Point start;
    File f = new File("Maze1.txt");
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
      final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
      mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
      for (int i = 0; i < mazeRow.length(); i++) {
        if (mazeRow.charAt(i) == 'S') {
          start = new Point(row, i);
          stack.push(start);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

After initialization, follow one of the algorithms that are provided above.